# Using AirPort DHCP relay agent info to assign IP by policy from server 2012

Tags: dhcp, apple

We have recently setup a Windows server 2012 DHCP server, with one scope of 10.0.0.0/16

We have a couple of policies in place to make sure certain ranges are assigned to certain devices, e.g. Thin Clients are on the 10.0.3.1 - 253 range.

I have now installed an AirPort extreme network in bridged mode, so the DHCP server is currently assigning IP addresses, not the AirPort extreme.

Is there a way to create a policy that says anything connecting via the AirPort extreme should have an IP in a certain range? I think this could be done if the AirPort was a relay agent, but my understanding is it is only a relay agent if it were on a different subnet?

Also, I am not sure how to find information about the relay agent from the AirPort extreme.

Appreciate any advice on the subject.

Comment: In your scenario the Airport is nothing more than a switch. Switches move packets (unaltered) from one interface to another. I don't see how you could identify a DHCP Request as having come through one particular switch.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I think my solution is to enable relay-agent on the port the AirPort is connected to on our Cisco switch. Then set a subscriber ID, and use that to set a DHCP policy. Once I have tested, I will add as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I think due to our particular network implementation, DHCP relay was not an effective option.

We decided to create a new VLAN, and set the IP helper-address on the interface for the VLAN.

All wireless clients where then placed onto that VLAN, and the DHCP server was then given a second scope to assign a different set of IP addresses.